# Multiple Id's in jquery classes

Tags: jquery, class, select

```
 echo '<span class="button_class"><a class="subscribe" id="subscr_';
echo $row['provider_id'];
echo '" href="javascript:;">&nbsp;Subscribe&nbsp;</a></span>';
```

I use the above code to subscrube to channels. Can i insert the channel name in that class ?
eg- channel name : CNN , How can i insert another id to the class subscribe ?

,
As i will be using jquery to ajax and subscribe and i want to alert saying ' Subscribed to CNN'. How to get CNN from the class while using jquery ?

eg : ID2="CNN"

Answer (score 3):

If you want to store basic data in your tags, you can use the `data-*` attributes, i.e `<span id="abc" data-id2="CNN"></span>`, which you can easily get via jQuery using `$("#abc").data("id2");`, to set the values you do `$("#abc").data("id2","new Value");`

Answer (score 2):

Use a data attribute instead, for example:

```
<a class="subscribe" id="subscr_provider" data-provider-name="CNN"></a>
```

Then:

```
$("#subscr_provider").data("provider-name");
// or
$("#subscr_provider").attr("data-provider-name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply separate the class names with a space inside the quotes:

```
echo '<span class="button_class"><a class="subscribe CNN" id="subscr_';
echo $row['provider_id'];
echo '" href="javascript:;">&nbsp;Subscribe&nbsp;</a></span>';
```

While this would probably work, I'm a bit confused by your request because you intermix 'class' & 'ID'.  The suggestions for using 'data–' are probably more useful, and a good technique to learn.